# Sou Iniciante e estou tentando Fazer Cadastro e Login com Firebase porem com erros que não consigo resolver

Tags: firebase, autenticação, kotlin

Estou seguindo um tutorial que vi no Youtube porem o meu não deu certo... helpe me please....

Pelo Debug vi que o erro inicia dentro das funções private fun creatOrLoginUser:
preciso criar uma tela que faça cadastro no firebase e login, e depois autenticação com google e facebook, porem nao consigo nem passar dessa parte, sou novo na programação e escolhir iniciar por kotlin pois achei mais simples que java... alguem pode me ajudar nisso?

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Build
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.github.dhaval2404.imagepicker.ImagePicker
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext


class telaLogin : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private var firstTimeUser= true
    private var fileUri: Uri? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        buttonClicks()

    }

    private fun buttonClicks(){
        btn_login.setOnClickListener{
            firstTimeUser = false
            creatOrLoginUser()
        }

        btn_register.setOnClickListener {
            creatOrLoginUser()
        }

        iv_profileImage.setOnClickListener{
            selectImage()
        }
    }

    private fun creatOrLoginUser(){
        val email = et_emailLogin.text.toString()
        val password = et_passwordLogin.text.toString()

        if(email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty()){
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
                try {
                    if(firstTimeUser){
                        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).await()
                        auth.currentUser.let {
                            val update = UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().setPhotoUri(fileUri).build()

                            it?.updateProfile(update)

                        }?.await()

                    } else{
                        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
                    }

                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                        Toast.makeText(this@telaLogin, "Login Realizado com Sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        val intent = Intent(this@telaLogin, TelaUsuario::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                    }

                }catch (e:Exception) {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                        Toast.makeText(this@telaLogin, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

   private fun checkIfUserLoggedIn(){
       if(auth.currentUser != null){
           val intent = Intent(this@telaLogin, TelaUsuario::class.java)
           startActivity(intent)
           finish()
       }
   }


    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        checkIfUserLoggedIn()
    }

    private fun selectImage(){
        ImagePicker.with(this)
            .crop()
            .compress(1024)
            .maxResultSize(1080, 1080)
            .start()
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        when(resultCode){
            Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                fileUri = data?.data
                iv_profileImage.setImageURI(fileUri)
            }
            ImagePicker.RESULT_ERROR -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, ImagePicker.getError(data),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Tarefa Cancelada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

o erro que está aparecendo:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.personalfitness, PID: 8439
    java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.example.personalfitness.telaLogin$creatOrLoginUser$1: java.lang.Object com.example.personalfitness.telaLogin$creatOrLoginUser$1.invokeSuspend(java.lang.Object) failed to verify: java.lang.Object com.example.personalfitness.telaLogin$creatOrLoginUser$1.invokeSuspend(java.lang.Object): [0x107] register v3 has type Reference: java.lang.Exception but expected Precise Reference: kotlin.jvm.internal.Ref$ObjectRef (declaration of 'com.example.personalfitness.telaLogin$creatOrLoginUser$1' appears in /data/app/com.example.personalfitness-GTyuUkIpC72oD49ruXnAGQ==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
        at com.example.personalfitness.telaLogin.creatOrLoginUser(telaLogin.kt:58)
        at com.example.personalfitness.telaLogin.access$creatOrLoginUser(telaLogin.kt:23)
        at com.example.personalfitness.telaLogin$buttonClicks$1.onClick(telaLogin.kt:41)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6600)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6577)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:781)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25912)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8439 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8603', transport: 'socket'
```

ja nao sei o que fazer

Answer (score 0):

O erro acontece em tempo de execução. De acordo com o Log, o erro diz respeito a chamada GlobalScope.launch, que é uma chamada de corrotinas do Kotlin.

Me parece ser um bug da versão da biblioteca de corrotinas para a sua versão do Android, veja o link a seguir.
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2041

A solução seria reverter a versão da biblioteca de corrotinas de seu projeto para 1.3.6, ou atualizar para uma versão mais recente.

Em seu arquivo build.gradle, altere a biblioteca coroutines-android para:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.6'
```